# php pthreads crashes, how to debug?

Tags: php, pthreads

Our project using pthreads, and for the first time it was pertty simple, bu then functions and features were added and at some point pthreads begun to crash.

```
Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 7.0.6.0, time stamp: 0x57227780
Faulting module name: php7ts.dll, version: 7.0.6.0, time stamp: 0x57227f4d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000170bb
Faulting process id: 0x9e0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1a6ad3e402fd0
Faulting application path: C:\php7\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\php7\php7ts.dll
Report Id: 11816c60-12a1-11e6-8c59-f8169b6275a3
```

We using pthreads 3.1.6, win2008 x64 and php 7.0.6. So the question is - how to debug the reason of this issue? Looks like it crashes when new thread object created. How can I debug it to be sure?

If it hepls - run method runs curl and mysqli in process (we are collecting data from pages and storing some results). Thank you!

Comment: use gdb to debug, put breakpoints. Or use 'printf' in your code to see where is the error.

Comment: Its php pthreads, I mean php debugger. I'am trying to use xdebug now, at this point didnt find out hothing new.